# Printing out register value in ADS 1.2(ARM Assembly)

Tags: assembly, arm, ads

I'm using ARM developer suite 1.2(ARM7TDMI) and I have a problem with printing out register value in AXD console.

As far as I know, to print out register values in AXD Console, I should convert register values(binary) to BCD, then change each digits to ascii code(e.g. 0 to '0')

In my opinion, using method which I write above takes too much cost and bit complicated.

Are there any easy way to print out register value by easy way(using only assembly)?

Comment: That's how you print numbers. It's what any `Print` function would do, if you were linking to a library. (Which is why libraries are so nice.) It isn't that hard to implement, and generally requires only a few shifts and adds in a loop.

Comment: you can print them in hex or octal instead of decimal.  or binary...